# Show that $c$ is a characteristic value of $f(T)$ if and only if $c=f(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$.Let $f$ be a polynomial over $F$.

> Prove that $c$ is a characteristic value of $f(T)$ if and only if $c=f(t)$ where $t$ is a characteristic value of $T$.

**My try**:

If I assume that $c=f(t)$ where $t$ is a characteristic value of $T$ then $T\alpha=t\alpha$ for some $\alpha\neq 0$.

let $c=f(t)=a_0+a_1t+\ldots +a_nt^n\implies c\alpha=(a_0+a_1t+\ldots +a_nt^n)\alpha\hspace{80mm}=a_o\alpha+a_1t\alpha+a_2t^2\alpha+\ldots +a_nt^n \alpha\hspace{80mm}=a_0\alpha+a_1T\alpha+a_2T^2(\alpha)+\ldots +a_nT^n(\alpha)\hspace{80mm}=f(T)\alpha$

Hence proved.

Conversely,since $c$ is a characteristic value of $f(T)$; $f(T)\alpha=c\alpha\implies a_0\alpha+a_1T\alpha+a_2T^2(\alpha)+\ldots +a_nT^n(\alpha)=c\alpha$

**However I am unable to show that $c=f(t)$ for required $t$**?

Please give some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that that $f(T)\alpha=c\alpha$. As $F$ is algebraically closed, then the polynomial $f(x)-c=0$ is factorised in $F$:
$$
f(x)-c=(x-t_1)\cdots (x-t_k), \quad t_1,\ldots t_k\in F.
$$
In particular
$$
0=\big(f(T)-c\big)\alpha=(T-t_1)\cdots (T-t_k)\alpha
$$
If none of the $t_1,\ldots t_k$ were characteristic values of $T$, then $(T-t_1)\cdots (T-t_k)$ would be nonsingular and $(T-t_1)\cdots (T-t_k)\alpha\ne 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: How are you writing $f(x) - c = (x-t_1) \cdots (x-t_k)$? It can be of the form $f(x) - c = (x-t_1)^{2} \cdots (x-t_k)^2$. Then $(f(T) - c)(\alpha) $ can also imply that $(T-t_i)^2(\alpha) = 0$ for some $i$

Comment: @Antimony If $(T-t_i)^ka=0,$ with $a\ne 0$ and $k$ a positive integer, then this still implies that $t_i$  still an eigenvalue if $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement to Bob's answer note that algebraically closed is essential.
$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $f(x)=x^2$ then $f(T)=\begin{pmatrix} -1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ with eigevalue $-1$ that is not of the form $t^2=-1$ for a real field.